# Installing Kali Linux along with Windows 10

Tags: security, windows, kali-linux, system-installation

I have recently purchased an ASUS ROG GL552vw from UK and its pre-installed with windows 10, I'm trying to install Kali Linux as the second OS but the PC can't boot from CD/DVD or even from a bootable USB, Computers with Microsoft Windows 10 signature can't be overwritten with another OS or Can't be dual booted.

Comment: virtual machine is a good choice, but this is not an answer to the question, laptops come with protected USB ports cuz of security, so one option is to go to the bios and allow boot from USB, or like change the boot type from legacy to UEFI, I don't know, there are a lot of different reasons that he can't install Kali

Answer (score 1):

Use virtualbox, disable secure boot in bios, ask ASUS, or replace your hardware with something more open.